# Trying to install Puppet Enterprise on Linux 7 and getting Certification error

Tags: linux, puppet

This is what I get as root on my Linux 7:
sudo rpm -ivh https://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-el-7.noarch.rpm
Retrieving ...

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
error: skipping https://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-el-7.noarch.rpm - transfer failed

**I am I getting blocked by firewall ? I can ssh to self and port 3000 is open, any idea would be appreciated, thank you  **

Comment: Does it work if you use the -k option?

Comment: it does not work with -k option either

Comment: You could try downloading the rpm manually via a web browser or curl and then install it from your local file system.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want to stay away from that route.